# Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to two ListNode swift

Tags: swift, linked-list

I have searched on the Internet without any useful result. My question is very simple. How to compare two ListNode is equal or not? For example:

```
// plused is a ListNode
if plused != head?.next { // Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to two ListNode 
    head?.val += 1
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this in Swift?

---

Edit, July 31, 2016:

These two nodes are declared as class instance

Comment: Try the identity operator `!==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should be using identity operator for comparing instances.

- Equal : ===
- Not Equal : !==

**Sample Code:**

```
if instance1 === instance { print("Equal") }
if instance1 !== instance { print("Not Equal") }
```

**Updated Example:** *Solution in Swift*

```
class ListNode {
    init() { print("Initializing node") }
}

class Head {
    var next: ListNode
    init(withNode node: ListNode) { next = node }
}

let plused = ListNode()
let head = Head(withNode: plused)

//(plused != head.next) ? print("Equal") : print("Not Equal")
(object_getClass(plused) == object_getClass(head.next)) ? print("Equal") : print("Not Equal")
```

Let me know if this solution resolves your query.

Comment: I learnt from the Swift doc that `===` means two instances are inherited from **the same class**. Well, here two nodes do inherit from the same class, but they might be not the same node. Am I correct?

Comment: @JW.ZG: The identity operator `===` checks whether its two operands are the _exact same instance_ of an object, i.e., whether it is two variables pointing to the same reference. This may or may not be what you want, it depends on the implementation details of your linked list. `==` checks for equality (whether the operands are semantically equivalent), and is self-defined by each type.

Comment: @JW.ZG  : **'==='** means that two constants or variables of class type refer to exactly the same class instance. Referred from [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82).

But in your case, what are the types of 'plused' & 'head?.next'. I mean is it declared as class or Struct?

Comment: @Tesan3089 They are declared as class. So I wondered `===` will not be helpful here because as you said **refer to exactly the same class instance**.  I want to know whether they are the same node, instead of **refer to** the same class instance.

Answer (score 1):

`!=` is an operator provided by the `Equatable` protocol. If your `ListNode` type (struct, class, etc.) doesn't conform to that protocol (by implementing the `==` function), then you won't be able to use `!=` against them.